# How to get after slash url params on index.php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am going to create a project in php

When i hit this below url in address bar
http://10.16.70.70/myproject/user/login

It show an error below

**Not Found**

**The requested URL /jween/user/login was not found on this server.**

**Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.16.70.70 Port 80**

my htaccess code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

What i want, when i hit this url **http://10.16.70.70/myproject/user/login**

i want to get **user/login** in query string on my index.php page using htaccess

Comment: jween and myproject are  the same ?

Comment: Enable the rewrite log, and see how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

Your **.htaccess** look like this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /myproject/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And your **index.php** file look like this (Only for testting purpose)

```
<?php
     echo "<pre>"; print_r($_GET); echo "</pre>";die;
```

I think this is helpful for you :)

Thanks